# Css: Create a separate table in the same background border

Tags: css, html

I am trying to add a "beverage" section to the bottom center of this menu page. Not only is the spacing inaccurate of my goal/vision, but I cannot get both sets of data (from the food items to the beverages) contained within the same background color "brown". Any thoughts on how to get my head to stop spinning? Ay, yi, yi!
Here's the full code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RestaurantStyles4.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arima+Madurai" rel="stylesheet">
 <style type="text/css"> table.table1{background-color: brown; border-bottom: solid transparent; margin-bottom:40px; color:white;}
 body{background-color: #FF8C00;}

   </style>
        <title id="menu">Menu Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <hr>
    <h1 align=center>The Sweet Potato </h1>
    <hr>
    <a href="Restaurant 4 Home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="Restaurant 4 Menu.html">Menu</a>
  <a href="Restaurant 4 Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    <table width="100%" align="center" class="table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <tr align=center>       
        <th>Burger and Fries</th>
        <th>Hot Dog and Chips</th>
        <th>Italian Sausage and Peppers</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align=center>
     <td>An American Classic!</br>
          Your choice - with or without cheese</br>
          Pickle, onion, tomato, and lettuce </br>
          Served with our famous thick cut french fries</br>
          </br>
          $7.95</td>
          </br>
    <td>An Summer Classic!<br>
          Your choice - white or wheat bun</br>
          Relish, mustard, and ketchup</br>
          Served with our house-made chips</br>
          </br>
          $7.95</td>
          </br>
    <td>An All-Time Favorite!!</br>
          Your choice - mild or spicy</br>
          Cole Slaw</br>
          Served with garlic mashers</br>
          </br>
          $10.95</td>
          </br>
          <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          </tr>
        <tr align=center>
          <th>Tenderloin Sandwich and Chips</th>
          <th>House Salad</th>
          <th>Brisket Sandwich and Fries</th>
        </tr>
        <tr align=center>
          <td>Really Hits the Spot!</br>
          Plain or Sesame Seed Bun</br>
          Pickle, onion, tomato, and lettuce</br>
          Served with our house-made chips</br>
          </br>
          $8.95</td>
          <td>On the Lighter Side!</br>
          Your choice - with or without cheese</br>
          Iceberg lettuce, tomatoes, peppers
          Thousand Island or Ranch Dressing</br>
          Served with a dinner roll</br>
          </br>
          $6.95</td>
          <td>A Taste of Texas!</br>
         Smoked Brisket on thick-cut Texas Toast</br>
          Cole Slaw</br>
          Served with our famous thick-cut
          french fries</br>
          </br>          
          $7.95</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center" >
          <th>Beverages</th>
        </tr>
         <tr><td>Root Beer</td><td>$3.00</td>
        </tr>
         <tr><td>Root Beer</td><td>$3.00</td>
        </tr>
         <tr><td>Root Beer</td><td>$3.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Root Beer</td><td>$3.00</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <footer>
        <div align="center">1010 Meatandpotato Lane, Ohio City, OH, 88888</div>
        <div align="center">216-867-5309</div>
    </footer>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Can you reformat your post so that all of the code is readable?

Comment: Oooh... Need to repost question; formatting has gone crazy.

Comment: Okay....it should be readable now. Thanks for taking a look everyone!

Comment: Also... I try <div> tags often....but I am new to this. I am having a hard time with understanding their absolute purpose and concept.